# How to make a specific parameter unique in Java

Tags: java, parameters, unique-constraint

How can I make sure that each instance of a class will have a unique value for a specific parameter?
For example:
public Foo(int value);
value should be different for each instance of Foo. Otherwise, it can throw an exception.

Comment: Can you post your code? what you have done so far?

Comment: You could store the values in a Set and check if it's not already in. But your issue smells like a design flaw, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to assign that value, or do you just want to make sure you have some kind of id?

A minimal solution for an id would be to use a static field as counter:

```
public class Foo {

  private static int counter = 1;
  private int id;

  public Foo() {
    id = counter++;
  }
}
```

To check for assigned values you might want to use some kind of FooFactory:

```
public class FooFactory {

  private static Set<int> ids = new Set<int>();

  public static Foo createFoo(int value) {
    if (ids.contains(value)) {
      throw new FooAlreadyExistsException();
    }

    ids.add(value);
    return new Foo(value);
  }
}
```

Or, as other comments suggest, you could do this in the Foo constructor:

```
public class Foo {

  private static Set<int> ids = new Set<int>();

  public Foo(int value) {
    if (ids.contains(value)) {
      throw new FooAlreadyExistsException();
    }

    ids.add(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a factory:

```
public Foo createFoo( int value ) {....}
```

In the factory code, you can maintain a set of "allocated" values. This allows you to optimize the code; for example if the values are consecutive, a `BitSet` might be better than `Set<Integer>`. Note that you must "deallocate" your instances of `Foo` somehow if you want to be able to reuse values.

If you just GC instances of `Foo`, the value will still be "in use" unless  you notify the factory somehow.

Comment: This is IMO the best suggestion so far.

Comment: Vote for best answer +1 !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all instances of Foo would be in memory, you can maintain a static Set in the Foo class that would hold the values that were already used. You can check against this Set any time a new instance is created.

Another alternative, assuming there is no functional meaning to this value, is to have some sequence (backed by either a DB or a file) that would increment any time a new instance is created, and the value of each new instance would be the current value of that sequence.

Comment: You either need a `Set<Integer>` or a `Map<Integer, Foo>`, otherwise, you can't do a quick lookup. Also note that this solution creates a memory leak.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I suggested a Set. I don't think a Map is necessary.

Comment: But if duplicate present then what shall do? is it create object?  If i don't what to create object then.

Comment: @atishshimpi According to the OP, an exception should be thrown in case of a duplicate.

Comment: @Eran: `Set<Foo>` has two drawbacks: 1. You need to create an instance to check whether a value is allocated. 2. It keeps instances of `Foo` around which could create a memory leak.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I never suggested a `Set<Foo>`. I suggested `Set in the Foo class that would hold the values that were already used`. That means a `Set<Integer>`, since the values are integer.

Comment: Vote for best answer  +1 !

Answer (score 1):

I think your unique value should not be a parameter (which is under control of an arbitrary caller) but a responsibility of Foo.

A simple solution would be to use a static field which is incremented each time an instance is created:

```
private static int instanceCounter;

// instance initializer
{
    instanceCounter++;
}
```

As others have mentioned this smells of a problem in your design or your understanding of the requirements.

Please share the requirements, your intended design and the code you have created so far.

EDIT: 'Aaron Digulla' has a better suggestion, to create a factory which manages this aspect of the object lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose having a static ArrayList inside of a class, containing a list of your objects. But this is bad design IMHO.